# Which universities are best for studying Oceanography as an undergrad?

Tags: oceanography

I am a high school senior studying in a local school in Bangladesh. My passion is to study oceans & marine life. The drive of getting higher education in Oceanography has turned into ardent compassion for me. I am, therefore, seeking insightful & important pieces of information regarding which universities would be best for higher education in Oceanography.
Your guidance & help is much wanted & would be highly appreciated.
<3

Comment: The one thing that may really make people hesitate on this question is that you didn't give much idea of region.  Are you talking globally?  Or are you leaning more towards that part of the world?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that there is a push to close the question, and I get why. But I do think that guidance towards a university is still important, even if it does not fit the Earth Science SE guidelines. So here is my answer (as someone who does not study oceanography, rather as a meteorologist): It depends.

What I have found is that the question you should ask is not 'what is the best,' rather 'what is the best *for me*?' You may want to learn from the best, but you might end up miserable. What can you afford? How far are you willing to travel for your degree? What aspects of oceanography are you interested in -- chemistry, climatology, biology, geology, etc.? Presumably, different universities will emphasize different specialties. Look at what the faculty research, and you will find what

Knowledge is knowledge. With solid reading skill and good resources, you can probably teach yourself enough without needing a degree. If it is just a passion, I would recommend that route. If it is what you want as a career, go to university and get the degree.

Comment: Sabiha's question is exactly the one I asked as a high school senior (except for meteorology).  And while I then and now certainly get your points about how aspects change things, I'm still grateful people stepped up and recommended universities particularly known in the field for broad strength.  Because I didn't know the answers to which subfield or how I would do with the more challenging work or distance... and I doubt most high schoolers do.  Maybe there should be summer intro programs to get a better taste in such subjects.

Comment: But I really do get where Sabiha is coming from, and am disappointed in the push to close.  Because reflecting again to meteorology, it's quite difficult to just get a list of what schools offer it... and then obviously those offerings range from a course or two from one professor to the stalwart schools.  And having a rough idea of some schools that have a broader standing would be great for people trying to enter fields like ours, and lead to less lost people and wasted money.  So hopefully someone with such knowledge can offer a bit.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't seem perfect for SE, but I would think a little tweaking could make it work.  Many sites allow open ended requests for software recommendations\research material\etc... would think it could work here, within some guideline frameworks.

Comment: Question belongs on https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @farrenthorpe you really think so?  I can't find any similar questions (maybe I didn't search well?), and it seems a bit of a stretch to fit any of the topics to ask about on https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (only possibly working in the last option... but it's not really about studying or teaching itself, but about where to go to study)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest While I haven't been active lately, I've generally noticed EarthScience stack stick to the science questions.  I remember trying to ask opinion-based questions like this one and getting shot down.  Academia has a pretty "opinion-friendly" format.